# Button opens Tabbed Web browser between forms

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, browser, tabcontrol

I am having some difficulty connecting a method to two different wpf forms. I have not written methods in months and I am new to c#. Feels like I am missing something obvious... Anyway, I am creating a button in the "Main Window" form called "FacebookButton" that when clicked, opens a **tab** in Window 2 to the website, www.facebook.com.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FacebookButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 facebookWindow = new Window2();
        facebookWindow.Show();
        facebookWindow.facebookNewTab;
    }
}
```

And Window 2 is...

```
 public partial class Window2 : Window
{


    public WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void facebookNewTab()
    {
        TabItem tp = new TabItem();
        tp.Header = "Facebook";
        wb.Navigate("http://facebook.com");
        tp.Content = wb;
        tabControl.Items.Add(tp);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to make `Window2.facebookNewTab` a `public` or `internal` method so you can invoke it from `MainWindow`. You can only invoke private methods from within the containing type.

```
public void facebookNewTab()
{
    //Code here...
}
```

There is also an issue with this line of code:

> facebookWindow.facebookNewTab;

Currently this is not invoking the `facebookWindow.facebookNewTab` method. When you leave the parentheses off a method it signifies a pointer to a method which is used in a `delegate`. Updating your code to invoke the method should fix it.

```
private void FacebookButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window2 facebookWindow = new Window2();
    facebookWindow.Show();
    facebookWindow.facebookNewTab();
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I understand now. I knew I was missing something simple.. Thanks!